# gitlab docker log is filled with "failed to access wifi data: permission denied"

Tags: docker, gitlab

I installed gitlab docker following the document at described at: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html

After installation, I have backed up the gitlab data from old server and restored in the new server.

At this state all is fine but my log is filled with below error.

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 11:34:23 +0000
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
Filter chain halted as :validate_prometheus_metrics rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/current <==
2017-08-14_11:34:30.58806 ::1 - - [14/Aug/2017:11:34:30 UTC] "GET /sidekiq HTTP/1.1" 200 3399
2017-08-14_11:34:30.58809 - -> /sidekiq
2017-08-14_11:34:32.51269 ::1 - - [14/Aug/2017:11:34:32 UTC] "GET /database HTTP/1.1" 200 42149
2017-08-14_11:34:32.51272 - -> /database
==> /var/log/gitlab/node-exporter/current <==
2017-08-14_11:34:33.97247 time="2017-08-14T11:34:33Z" level=error msg="ERROR: wifi collector failed after 0.000044s: failed to access wifi data: permission denied" source="node_exporter.go:95" 
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/current <==
2017-08-14_11:34:34.78141 ::1 - - [14/Aug/2017:11:34:34 UTC] "GET /process HTTP/1.1" 200 2212
2017-08-14_11:34:34.78143 - -> /process
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
```

The error to highlight here is "**ERROR: wifi collector failed after 0.000044s: failed to access wifi data: permission denied**"

I do not see any side effect caused due to this error yet but it does run almost every 10 seconds causing the log to be full.

Can some explain:

- What this error mean?
- What can I do to stop this error from running in loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is caused due to SELinux.  GitLab is fixing is.  the issue is reported and confirmed here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36559